# enabling write cache on existing RAID arrays

Tags: raid

I have an Adaptec 3805 RAID controller and with two arrays without write cache. Now that I have bought the battery module for this controller, can I now enable the write cache on the existing arrays? Or do I need to delete and re-create new arrays with write cache on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enable/disable the write cache without any other modifications. Just use the same management software you use to create/delete arrays.
You even won't have to reboot.

But I think you make a mistake about `Adaptec 3805 RAID controller [...] without write cache`. This controller have a write cache. You can use it without the battery. But in case of power loss, the content of the cache is not written to disk.

The purpose of battery backed-up write cache is to allow the cache to be written on disk next time you power on the system.

Comment: Many controllers will not use write caching without a battery

Comment: Got it. I enabled it under Adaptec Storage Manager. I thought it could not be enabled on existing arrays. Thanks!